# EF Core - Pulling Data From Two Identical Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-core-2.2

TLDR: I have a two tables with identical definitions, and I need to pull from one table *or* the other depending on some switch.

For example, assume a table with a bunch of "generic" `FooItem` and a table with "Fancy" `FooItem`... and the only difference between the two tables is the names, `SIMPLE_FOO` and `FANCY_FOO`

Depending on a boolean value, like `GetFancy == true`, I should read from `FANCY_FOO`, otherwise, `SIMPLE_FOO`.

This gets a complicated in the `DbContext`.  I can't have more than one `DbSet<FooItem>` in my context, and I can't dynamically "inject" the table name in the `ModelBuilder.Entity<FooItem>(e => e.ToView("pickOne"))`  ... and I don't want to duplicate an entire dbContext just to have a different table name in there.

I'm sure the solution is simple, but I'm just not seeing it.  Any assistance is appreciated.

**EDIT:**  I cannot change the database.  It's a dumb way to do it, but that's the way they did it and I have to live with it.

Comment: Having two identical tables with the same schema is probably not a good route to take.  This should be one table with an extra boolean field `Fancy` that can differentiate records from each other.  This way you only need one DbContext reference and you can use LINQ queries to get the records that are "Fancy" or records that are "Simple".  Just my two cents

Comment: I am just working with the data structure I've got.  I wouldn't've designed it this way, but I cannot change the data structure - this database is decades old and not under my authority

Comment: You don't need to duplicate the entire DbContext, just create two duplicate entities  (or derive two from a common base class) with different names and then have two DbSets.  Or did you mean you didn't want to duplicate the DbSet?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance I think what you want is TPT (Table per Type) but i am not sure this is implemented in EF Core already

Comment: @BryanLewis I don't see how that could be done, could you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do, in my opinion, is to leverage the `.FromSql()` method and use that to choose which table:

```cs
var foos = GetFancy
  ? dbContext.FromSql(select * from FANCY_FOO)
  : dbContext.FromSql(select * from SIMPLE_FOO)

return foos.Where(/* etc /*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have two entities in your solution, one for each table.  They can inherit from a base class since they are identical.  Create your base class "BaseFooItem" that has all of the fields in both tables.  Then create an entity class for each of the variants (Simple and Fancy) and annotate each to match the necessary table name; e.g.:

```
[Table("SIMPLE_FOO")]
public class SimpleFooItem: BaseFooItem {
}
```

If you don't want to use data annotations, you can set the table name with the FluentAPI too.  Then create a DbSet for each entity:

```
    public DbSet<SimpleFooItem> SimpleFooItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FancyFooItem> FancyFooItems { get; set; }
```

Then do your conditional where ever to switch between each DbSet, for example:

```
if (GetFancy) {
   return dbContext.FancyFooItems.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
} else {
   return dbContext.SimpleFooItems.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

Hopefully I am understanding your needs correctly.

Comment: So in OnModelCreating I just build an entity for `FancyFooItems` and another for `SimpleFooItems` with the right table names?  Is there a way to refactor this so it isn't just copy/paste code?

Comment: Well, the actual DBSets are not inside of OnModelCreating but they are all inside of your DbContext class.  You can use the Fluent API to configure the table names inside of OnModelCreating if you don't want to use the annotations like I showed about. e.g. builder.Entity<SimpleFooItem>(a => a.ToTable("SIMPLE_FOO").  I can't think of a way to do it without two entities.  I am not aware of any way to do any dynamic switching.  You could use a stored procedure(s) if you want to bypass the EF stuff completely.